# ngOnInit not getting invoked after constructor: Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 5 for building an app where I am facing this issue where I navigate to a route and the execution stops after constructor, and UI is half loaded and then just stops loading. I added some console logs to ngOnInit and found that its not getting invoked. BUT, this only happens when the authentication token gets refreshed. Here is the httpInterceptor code that makes an http call along with the token.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

      constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Element, private 
adalService: AdalService, private injector: Injector) { }

      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.url !== '/config.json') {
        return this.getToken(request.url)
          .switchMap((token) => {
            if (this.adalService.userInfo) {
              this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated = true;
            }
        this.removeAdalFrame();
        return next.handle(request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }));
      }).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status == null) {
          console.log('Not recoverable error, logging out.');
          this.removeAdalFrame();
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
    } else {
      return next.handle(request.clone());
    }
  }

  private getToken(url): Observable<string> {
    return this.adalService.acquireToken(this.adalService.GetResourceForEndpoint(url)).delay(200);
  }

  private removeAdalFrame() {
    const iFrames = this.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (let i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++) {
      if (iFrames[i].id.startsWith('adalRenewFrame')) {
        iFrames[i].remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So whenever 'getToken' refreshes the token and reaches to microsoft to generate a new token when its expired then the problem starts. Some particular routerLinks break, that is, the child components are not loaded, some of the input properties don't propagate correctly from parent to child component, etc. Looks like some issue with the change detection happens. BUT, once I refresh the app everything starts working as expecting again, that is, the weird behavior only happens for the session when the token is refreshed. Once the app is releoaded, everything works like normal again.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: For what it's worth this is not standard syntax: `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Element`. https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

Comment: I don't see in your code where you're using `ngOnInit`, but that only works for components and not Injectables

Comment: @ExplosionPills this is httpInterceptor after which the problem starts. This is not where I call ngOnInit.

Comment: No error in the console ?

Comment: Nope @GrégoryElhaimer . But I did notice that APP_INITIALIZER gets executed 2-3 times after a new token is generated